Pain in elbow tendons while lifting
I have started lifting weights 3 times a week in the beginning of the year. After about 3 months, I had to stop because the tendons in my elbows would hurt every time I did biceps curl or hammer curls.
I exclusively did other exercises for 2 months until I tried again but the problem persisted. After about another 1 or 2 months (i.e. 3 months of lifting followed by 3 to 4 months of not lifting), I asked my general practitioner about it. I told him that the problem had been going on for several months. But he just told me to continue sparing the area during my exercise and to maybe apply Voltaren. His assistant added that I may also take Ibuprofen.
I stated that my elbow tendons only hurt when I lift. I'm not in pain during any other activity, so taking something against pain feels wrong. But he told me that pain medication also helps against inflammations, which I probably have in my elbow tendons.
I have applied Voltaren and also Kytta, and have even popped the occasional Iboprofen pill. However, more months have passed but whenever I try to lift, my elbow tendons still hurt.
Is there something that helps better against inflammation than pain medication? I really feel like it should not be inflamed for this long.

First off, see a physiotherapist that assesses your elbow and gives you a personalised rehab plan!
As someone who is trainkng in physiotherapy, listens to a ton of podcasts with leading experts and reads a lot of literature on that, I'd say the overall suggestions made by @Avogadro are sound. Sparing the painful areas will not help in any way and your doctor's words reflect bad/old medical training there.
I would specify that most if not all tendon rehab programs involve 3-4 stages where you progress to the next stage if and only if you achieved the goal and your pain during and after training does never exceed 3-4/10, which can roughly be translated as "you feel it but it does not make you slow down or stop, wince, or otherwise react physiologically". The plan makes no difference between (partial) ruptures and inflammation since the starting point (weakened tendon with pain) and the desired goal (metabolic activation and renewed structure) are the same.
Phase 1: Progressive isometric loading up to approximately 80% of your former max.
Phase 2: progressive loading, dynamic but slow strength exercises up to approximately 90% of former max.
Phase 3: progressive loading in fast, dynamic strength exercises that move up to full load and speed (depending on sport-specific needs)
(Phase 4: progressively more and more competetive sport-specific training and movements)
The specifics differ from tendon to tendon but Phase 3 should involve aiming for symmetric ability (left and right).
A final word: Voltaren and Kytta are basically placebos. And pain pills after more than 2 weeks should be a flag to see a doctor.

I am not a doctor and cannot advise as to the correctness of what your GP has recommended.  My answer is opinion only from my experiences and with others training around me.
Pain
Pain is complex and has a lot of reasons it propagates to our brains.  Sometimes it's a stimulus telling us to stop doing something because of risk of harm.  In other cases it is a stimulus that has no real associative harm but triggers the same pathways.
The first thing to do it exactly what you did:  talk with you doctor.  Someone should always understand if there are signs that the pain is former rather than the later.  Trained professionals do come in many different forms, and a GP might not be the best person to give great advice after an initial inspection that has determined you're not specifically injuring yourself.  The next step could be to seek specific exercise science practitioners such as a physical therapist who's been trained on how to deal with pain and exercise.
Practical Advice
This is not medical advice
I've read a great deal about pain, experienced it myself in many forms, and observed it in training partners.  When pain doesn't come from a possible injury formation, the next reason is the later from above: it's complex and nuanced.
From reading what you've done, it sounds like you've not trained in a regular fashion prior to this.  Then, picked up training regularly and often (3x/wk).  Without knowing specifics, such as what are your exercises, how many reps, and how much weight, it would appears that in general, your weekly volume (reps * weight) for exercises that require grip strength (curls, rows, pull downs, etc.) has increased too fast.
Recommendation
Find a pathway to do exercises that are more comfortable through lowering reps or weight until you've reached a point of low to no pain.  Also, find movements that adjacently trigger the use of those muscles such as grip strengthener and keep that weight low to no pain as well.
Over time, add either more weight or reps to challenge your muscles and pain tolerance.  Some pain is okay as long as it is tolerable and not increasing dramatically.  Take time to rest or use ice after a workout if your pain persists.  Otherwise, be practical and use this as an opportunity to not only progressively get more muscle, but to handle the new challenges with your pain.
Reference
I have found that Barbell Medicine's article on pain to be quite enlightening and encompassing of many of the ideals of how to overcome pain in training using evidence based reasoning.
